# Ruby on Rails Take String Input of a Time and store it as an integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently we are working with a user input of time.

We want to take the input in as a string which would be most natural for a user
ex. 12:30, 1:30.

Note that the times are not based on a specific date, but rather just a time of day.

However in our model we want the actual time to be stored as an integer(seconds after midnight). We need it as an integer to do certain constraint checking and what not.  It will also be easy for us to then output a nice string again with

```
Time.at().utc.strftime("%I:%M%p")
```

The problem we are running into is that we want to validate the string input by the user with a regex before converting it to seconds after midnight and storing it. 
However it seems that before our model validates_by_format the field has already been converted to some kind of integer type. Any ideas on how we can use a regex to check the user input before we convert and store it as an integer(seconds after midnight)?

Here are some of our code snipits:

The model validate

```
validates_format_of :start_time, :with => /\A(1[0-2]|[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\z/, :message => "Must be valid time format"
```

The fields in our table

```
start_time :integer
end_time   :integer
```

The controller function

```
def create
    @course_offering = current_term.course_offerings.new(params[:course_offering]) 

    if @course_offering.save
        #flash[:success] = "Offering created"
        @conflicts = conflicts(@course_offering)
        render :show
    else
        render :new
    end
  end
```

The new view

```
<% form_for @course_offering do |f| %>
<!-- other fields above this -->
<p>
    <%= f.label :start_time %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :start_time %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :end_time %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :end_time %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please, post your new.html.erb or equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We eventually solved our dilemma.  We kept start_time and end_time as integers, but we used a virtual attribute in the model to take the string input in the model.

```
# our new fields
<p>
  <%= f.label :start_time_string %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :start_time_string %>
</p>

# model
def start_time_string
  Time.at(start_time + 5*3600).strftime("%l:%M %p") if !start_time.nil?
end

def start_time_string=(start_time_str)
  self.start_time = Time.parse(start_time_str).seconds_since_midnight 
end
```

That way our user can input times like '12:30 PM', but it's saved as a nice time after midnight.

Answer (score 1):

I would use custom validation method that checks if it is possible to parse user input to a valid time, something like this in model:

```
validate :user_must_enter_valid_time

def user_must_enter_valid_time
   errors.add(:start_time, "Incorrect format of start time") if
      !valid_time?(start_time) 
end

def valid_time?(time_string)
   begin
    parsed_input = Time.parse(time_string)
    #Checking if user entered time no earlier than 24 hours before current time
    return Time.now - parsed_input < 24 * 60 * 60 
   rescue Exception => e
    return false
   end
end
```

Comment: I am not positive what this is doing, but i don't see how this will bypass our problem of not being able to use the validate we wrote above. The problem is we are taking the input as a string in the view, want to validate the string is a valid input with our regex, then convert it to the integer(seconds after midnight) and store it as an integer value in start_time.

Comment: @febs - The first method is a new validation method that tells the app to add error if method valid_time?(start_time) returns false. Second method defines valid_time?(time_string). It returns false in two cases: a)string time_string cannot be converted to Time and returns exception, e.g. user entered "abcd"; b)time_string is parsed to a time that is earlier than 24 hours from Time.now, since I as far as I understand you need to validate this also. I edited code to make it nicer. Regex is nice, but it's harder to understand and it does not validate if user entered an earlier time than needed.

Comment: I like this method, but our problem is the actual passing of the value from the start_time field to the validation model. Also we are not trying to check if the time is before midnight, that is simply the way we are going to store time.  We're working with arbitrary times of day (with no date) so it seemed like a good idea. I gave the custom validation a shot, but when the user enters (12:30 or 1:53) the value is cut off at the hour number, I think it has something to do with the integer data type in the DB and our user's string input.